# How to validate array size based on a field in the request with Laravel Form Request

Tags: laravel, request

My request looks a bit like this:

```
"adults": {
    "count": 2,
    "persons": {
        [
            "name": "Anne",
            "surname": "Doe",

        ],    
        [
            "name": "Anne",
            "surname": "Doe",

        ],
    }
}
```

**How can I easily verify using a custom Request that the `count` field matches the size of the `persons`?**

Here's my Rules:

```
class CreateFamilyRequest extends ApiRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'adults' => ['array'],
            'adults.number' => ['int'],
            'adults.persons.*.name' => ['string'],
            'adults.persons.*.surname' => ['string'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in context of the `request`, so you can access it as you would in the `controller`, by using `$this` for current object context. Therefor you can just fetch out the size, assuming this is a `JSON` request, else change the input method.

```
'adults.persons' => ['array', 'size:' . $this->json('adults')['count'] ?? -1],
```

Comment: Both the validation key and the json access was wrong updated my answer.. Still the idea remain the same